# How to render non-database variables for a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called `Event` that has some attributes that are stored in the database and other attributes not stored. I do that with attr_accessor.

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
 attr_accessor :name, :location, :description
end
```

When I render an array of Events, `render json: @events`, only the stored attributes are displayed (such as id, created_at, updated_at, points...). How do I also display the non-database variables/attributes (such as name, location, and description)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`attribute`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attribute). This can be used to override Rails's choice of interpreting a database column, and it can also be used to add non-column attributes.

It takes a name and an optional type. You can also give a default.

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
 attribute :name
 attribute :location
 attribute :description, default: "Probably another music festival"
end
```

Comment: @Gavro Yes. The attribute documentation linked in the answer covers that.